# Manage margin with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I've an issue when I try to apply a margin on a container with absolutely positioned elements. This margin doesn't seems to be applied on the right end.

My template is a simple container with several elements :

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element first">
      0
    </div>
    <div class="element second">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="element third">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The container looks like this (height and width at 120% to have an overflow) :

```
.container {
  height: 120%;
  width: 120%;
  margin: 9px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

And the elements are some simple div with absolute position :

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;  
  width: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

I'm expecting the margin to be applied on every end of the container, even when this container is overflowing the `.app` element.

Here's the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThomasFerro/3cqdmx30/) to reproduce the issue and notice that the margin is fine everywhere else. Am I missing a point ?

Comment: Can you specify more exactly what your expected behavior is, and how it is different from what you observe? The fiddle seems to be working fine to me.

Comment: set your .container element display:inline-block

Comment: I've made an edit to explain to expected behavior.
@BrothermanBill your solution do the trick, can you make a proper answer so I can validate it ?

Comment: i think block elements always(if non float) try to get 100% of width or atleast browsers shows like that. it still have margin-right:9px but, you dont see it cuz of your width 120%. you can see margins with inspecting in developer tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the container is 120% and display: block. Just display inline-block an you'll get a margin on the right side. See the below example.

```css
html, body, .app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.app {
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  height: 120%;
  width: 120%;
  margin: 9px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;  
  width: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.first {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.second {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.third {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element first">
      0
    </div>
    <div class="element second">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="element third">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a great knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% certain if Im getting what you are trying to achieve, maybe make a little sketch of the expected outcome.

In case you want to shift your absolute elements 9px into the red box with that "margin", heres my answer:

Actually, the margin is also applied to your absolute elements, just not where you wanted.

Boxmodel has margin --> border --> padding from outside to inside and positioning is done at the start of border.

To do the trick, add a

```
 border: 9px solid red;
```

to your container in the fiddle, then you´ll have your 9px offset inside the redbox.

Comment: I've made an edit to explain a little bit more what I expect, sorry about the that.